# How should Genesis 3:4 be punctuated?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, grammar, syntax

In English usually after the word said we add a comma and a quote to designate when the speech began. In Hebrew I hope for some sort of structure language law. As an example:

> Genesis 3:4 (Hebrew OT, consonants only)
>   ויאמר הנחש אל האשה לא מות תמתון

- ויאמר - "and he will say" : say (אמר) . he will (י) . and (ו)
- הנחש - "the snake" : snake (נחש) . the (ה)
- אל - "I will to" : to (ל) . I will (א)
- האשה - "the woman" : woman (אשה) . the (ה)
- לא - "not"
- מות - "die"
- תמתון - "you will die little" : Diminutive (ון) . die (מת) . you will (ת)

Genesis 3:4, Raw Hebrew to English..

- Prefix suffix unstructured:

  > and he will say ˙ the snake ˙ I will to ˙ the woman ˙ not ˙ death ˙ you will die little
- Structure attempt version 1:

  > and he will say, "The snake I will to the woman not death. You will die little
- Structure attempt version 2:

  > and he said the snake, "I will to the woman not death you will die little
- Structure attempt version 3:

  > and he said the snake unto the woman, "Not death you will die little."

Also an example of a snake talking would be nice. Or the bible mentioning any other animal speaking prior to the time of Babylon.

Where should the quotes and the comma go?

Comment: Hebrew tells when a speaker starts speaking by context. Sometimes it's not obvious. If you have a specific question about where the beginning of direct speech is, tell us exactly where you're wondering about it. Questions like this need to start from a specific passage. A more general question about how Hebrew shows direct speech will have to wait for the [Hebrew site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language).

Comment: Focused on Genesis 3:4

Comment: There is no way of reliably telling when speech ends in Hebrew, though it usually clearly marks when a speaker begins. This is why I find Jeremiah a particularly fun book to translate, because it becomes to hard to tell where the Lord, Jeremiah and the people's words all begin and end (see Jer 8 and 9). Also, WRT _"Or the bible mentioning any other animal speaking prior to the time of Babylon"_... there are no other animals which speak in the first few chapters of Genesis, so this is the most weirdly specific question I've heard today!

Comment: I apologize what seems obvious to you apparently seems oblivious to me. Question specified.

Comment: I recommend actually studying Hebrew from a reputable program somewhere. There are online classes or you can even [purchase lectures on video that accompany a textbook](http://www.amazon.com/Learn-Biblical-Hebrew-Pack-Integrated/dp/0310523915/). Many of these questions and your answers show a complete ignorance of even the basics of the Hebrew language. I would also recommend a basic course in linguistics and semantics.

Comment: I also recommend reading these two meta posts: (1) [Strong's is a concordance, not a lexicon](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/923/); and (2) [Minimal Research Effort in Questions About the Original Languages](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/845/)

Comment: @Decrypted many local psychiatric wards, for starters.

Comment: @Dan I so believe what I see. I see the miracles of God so I believe in God. I hear the prophecies of God and see them over 50ish a day so I believe. I see the absolute truth about God everyday. I feel the rewards and the punishments from God from things I physically remember doing he does them to me. He shows me and everybody the truth about him everyday,. And what he has not ever showed me ever was a snake talking. So when I read what came from him and it does not match with what he shows me I try to figure out what it really means. My experience says snakes do not talk.

Comment: What version are you using and are you translating Genesis 3:4-5?

Answer (score 2):

The following excerpt may help, which comes from Page 95 of *[Biblical Hebrew for Beginners](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0281048185)* (London: Society for Promoting Christian Knowledge, 1996).

Based on the explanation, the translation appears below.

Please click on the image to enlarge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I need to straighten this first. I don't know how you got the Hebrew, because the Gen 3:4 I read is

> ויאמר הנחש
>   then said the serpent
>
> אל האשה
>   to the woman
>
> לא מות תמתון
>   Not death shall you get

How did you get the word "wife" or the word "age"? "Wife" is implicated when "woman" is used with a possessive. e.g., his woman, your woman. .

I don't think that [תמתון] means "shall die". I think [מתן] is a 2ndary root constructed from causative of [תן] give => get/be-recompensed.

Which means, the serpent was having a grammatical debate with the woman concerning verse 3. Because [תמתון] in verse three actually means

> פן תמתון
>    shall you otherwise be recompensed

The serpent questions the woman,

> did G'd say the word "death" when He said "recompensed"?

The fact that allowed the serpent to question "did G'd say death", is that verse 3 merely says [תמתון]="shall you-girl be recompensed". However, translators jumped the gun and somehow due to the presence of [מת] decided [תמתון] was an unusual but acceptable declension of [מת].

We need to read the Hebrew as it is written, not as we think it could be written.

#### Mode of punctuation:

The vav is often the used as punctuation. (Some people believe the vav also performs tense inversion, which is a completely nonsensical and anachronistic concept).

The vav is used a subsequence indicator, and therefore spontaneously punctuates a previous phrase.

For example in English,

> He came And he saw And he conquered And the people cheered.

I don't see how else more of an answer I could provide, because the Hebrew of this verse is rather plain and simple.